# mysql query needs different structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope I am able to explain this properly.
The following SQL generate a table like the following

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
FQ | <0 | 8-14 | 15-21 | 22-28 | >28
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
A  | 4  |  25  |  65   |  65   | 0
____________________________________
B  | 4  |  25  |  65   |  65   | 0
____________________________________
C  | 4  |  25  |  65   |  65   | 0
____________________________________
```

No here is what I need to to do and not sure if it's possible.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
         A  |  B  |  C  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
<0    |  4  |  4  |  4  |
_________________________
8-14  |  25 |  25 |  25 | 
_________________________
15-21 |  65 |  65 |  65 |
_________________________
22-28 |  65 |  65 |  65 |
_________________________
>28   |  0  |  0  |  0  |
```

This alternative will work as well.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
FQ | OverDueRange | DaysOverDue
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
A  | <0           |  4      |
_________________________
A  | 8-14         |  25     |
_________________________
A  | 15-21        |  65     |
_________________________
A  | 22-28        |  65     |
_________________________
A  | >28          |  0      |
_________________________
B  | <0           |  4      |
_________________________
B  | 8-14         |  25     |
_________________________
B  | 15-21        |  65     |
_________________________
B  | 22-28        |  65     |
_________________________
C  | >28          |  0      |    etc etc etc

SELECT 
    m.`FQ`,
    COUNT(a.`ID`) AS `< 0`,
    COUNT(b.`ID`) AS `0-7`,
    COUNT(c.`ID`) AS `8-14`,
    COUNT(d.`ID`) AS `15-21`,
    COUNT(e.`ID`) AS `22-28`,
    COUNT(f.`ID`) AS `> 28`
FROM
    `rhi_sap`.`dispatch report` m
        LEFT JOIN
    `rhi_sap`.`dispatch report` a ON a.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < CURDATE()
        AND m.`ID` = a.`ID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `rhi_sap`.`dispatch report` b ON b.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` > ADDDATE(CURDATE(), - 1)
        AND b.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 8)
        AND m.`ID` = b.`ID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `rhi_sap`.`dispatch report` c ON c.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` > ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
        AND c.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 15)
        AND m.`ID` = c.`ID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `rhi_sap`.`dispatch report` d ON d.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` > ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 14)
        AND d.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 22)
        AND m.`ID` = d.`ID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `rhi_sap`.`dispatch report` e ON e.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` > ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 21)
        AND e.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 29)
        AND m.`ID` = e.`ID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `rhi_sap`.`dispatch report` f ON e.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` > ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 28)
        AND m.`ID` = f.`ID`
WHERE
    m.`RHI_Freq_Class` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m.`RHI_Freq_Class`;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This is a question and answers site. But, where is the question in your post?

Comment: Not sure why, but the system removed some of the code.  Hope you will be able to understand my objective.

Comment: @user3361255 . . The `<pre>` tags interfere with your intentions.

Comment: What I am doing is creating Ranges by Count.   In that case I am counting records found where the difference from one date to today's date is greater than 28 days.

Comment: So what I need is the the Field Name `28` in this case to become part of the data returned with a new field name of OverDueRange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live without cumulative values, then I think something like this will work:

```
SELECT (case when m.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 28) then '28+'
             when m.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 22) then '22-28'
             when m.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 15) then '15-21'
             when m.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 8) then '8-14'
             when m.`RHI_TargetShip_Date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 1) then '1-8'
             else '0' 
        end) as grp,
       sum(FQ = 'A') as A,
       sum(FQ = 'B') as B,
       sum(FQ = 'C') as C
FROM rhi_sap.dispatch report m
WHERE m.`RHI_Freq_Class` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY MIN(m.`RHI_TargetShip_Date`)
```